# PHP & MySQL COUNT and ORDER BY results found

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have code like this:

```
function search_keyword(){       

        $keyword = $this->db->escape_like_str(trim($_POST['keyword']));

        $sql = " ( SELECT  name, id_global_info AS id, body AS body, tag AS tag  ,info_type_id AS info_type, \"global_info\" AS mytable FROM global_info WHERE ";
         $sql .= " MATCH (name, body, tag) AGAINST ( '$keyword') ";
          $sql .= " ) UNION ALL "; 

          $sql .= " ( SELECT name, id_person AS id, surname AS body, info AS tag , location AS info_type, \"person\" AS mytable FROM person WHERE ";
             $sql .= " MATCH (name, surname, info) AGAINST ( '$keyword' ) ";       

          $sql .= " ) UNION ALL ";

          $sql .= "( SELECT name, id_event AS id, body AS body, caffe_id AS tag , date AS info_type, \"event\" AS mytable FROM event WHERE ";
             $sql .= " MATCH (name, body) AGAINST ( '$keyword' ) ";             

        $sql .= " ) UNION ALL ";

          $sql .= "( SELECT name, id_caffe AS id, description AS body, adress AS tag, location_id AS info_type, \"caffe\" AS mytable FROM caffe WHERE ";
             $sql .= " MATCH (name, description) AGAINST ( '$keyword' ) ";           

        $sql .= " ) ";        
        $q = $this->db->query($sql);
         return $q = $q->num_rows() == 0 ? FALSE :  $q->result();
    }
```

How can I count number of results per row and then order them by count result?

Example:
I want to search word car - first row have name car, and in the body word car is appearing 7 times, and in second row car is appearing 2 times in the body. I want to count how many time word car is found and then order results by that count result.

Comment: cry, database, cry.

Comment: I updated the question. OZ I am just a begginer in MySQL. For the moment this way is working for me, but when I learn MySQL a bit more, I will remake the query. In any case, do you have suggestion how to fix query?

Comment: I think it's best that you did it using PHP:

Comment: what do you mean by  "per row " ? Do you mean it by each union query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best that you did it using PHP:

```
$counters = array();
foreach($q->result as $r)
  $counters[$r['mytable']]++;
```

Since I do not know your database interface, this is not exact code but I believe you can get the general idea (I am assuming that your resultset object is an array of associative arrays).

**Edit:**

*Alternate schema*

```
CREATE TABLE info_generic (id int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(100),
  record_type tinyint not null default 1, body TEXT, tag_id int , info_type_id int , 
  KEY (record_type) record_type,
  KEY(tag_id) tag_id,
  KEY(info_type_id) info_type_id
);

CREATE TABLE tags(id int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,  description VARCHAR(100) );

CREATE TABLE info_types(id int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
  description VARCHAR(100), record_type tinyint default 1 
);
```

*Attributes explained*

record_type : 1 -> global_info, 2 -> person , 3 -> event, 4 -> caffe

body        : 1 -> body       , 2 -> surname, 3 -> body , 4 -> description

tag         : 1 -> tag        , 2 -> info,    3 -> body , 4 -> description

You can then construct a single SQL using INNER JOINs to feed the records to Sphinx.

Comment: It is working. But from the number of likes which OZ comment get, I asume that I am doing something wrong with MySQL part and that I need it to change as soon as possible. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: We could remark on your schema that you may be using different tables for objects with common and similar attributes. You could combine them into one table thus saving you the trouble of performing this complex UNION query. One other solution is altering your schema and in the same time using a full-text search engine such as http://sphinxsearch.com . Note: I have edited my answer since it is too much info for a comment :).